# Constructing a syntax correct JSON file via BASH while loop

Tags: xml, bash, jq

Receive remote XML document (S3 bucket file listing), extract relevant keys and build syntax correct JSON file. File will be appended onto in the future.

Several iterations of applying filters for jq while passing an argument containing the value of the relevant element/string pair from XML source.

```
#! /bin/bash

baseUrl=https://hostname/tenant:bucket/
wget -q $baseUrl --output-document=output.xml

read_dom () {
    local IFS=\>
    read -d \< ELEMENT STRING
}

while read_dom; do
    if [[ $ELEMENT == "Key" ]] && [[ $STRING == *"string"* ]]; then
        if ! grep -Fxq "{\"name\":\"${STRING}\",\"value\":\"${STRING}\"}" deploy.json; then
            jq -cn --arg kv "${STRING}" '{name: $kv, value: $kv}' >> deploy.json
        fi
    fi
done < output.xml
```

Above is the full script which fetches the remote document (S3 bucket file listing), then iterates over the document with a while loop while filtering the contents of each Key for the specific filetype.

During the while loop, it iterates over the file `deploy.json` to grep for a no-match for the current `while` iteration value. If it doesn't find a match it proceeds to append it to the file as a new JSON object, otherwise it skips it.

Output from running the above script:

```
[user@hostname deploy]$ cat deploy.json
{"name":"someName1","value":"someValue1"}
{"name":"someName2","value":"someValue2"}
{"name":"someName3","value":"someValue3"}
{"name":"someName4","value":"someValue4"}
{"name":"someName5","value":"someValue5"}
{"name":"someName6","value":"someValue6"}
{"name":"someName7","value":"someValue7"}
```

What I need the output to be, is as follows:

```
[
  {"name":"someName1","value":"someValue1"},
  {"name":"someName2","value":"someValue2"},
  {"name":"someName3","value":"someValue3"},
  {"name":"someName4","value":"someValue4"},
  {"name":"someName5","value":"someValue5"},
  {"name":"someName6","value":"someValue6"},
  {"name":"someName7","value":"someValue7"}
]
```

The reason for the specific need of formatting for this list is the use case as an Option Model Provider for a Rundeck job. I'm trying to dynamically populate a list of deployment options as VM images are uploaded to S3 storage after their creation. As new images are created, this script will run during the cleanup stage and update the contents of the `deploy.json` file.

Regardless of what I try with jq, I can never get it quite right, I can feel that I'm right on the precipice of achieving it, but alas I lack the requisite experience with jq to articulate via syntax what is necessary to reach the summit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to take a step back, walk away then come back. Thanks for your suggestions peak and Aaron, but after going to sleep and waking up thinking about it for awhile after toying with the suggestions, jq was not actually necessary in achieving my goal, at least not in a rudimentary fashion.

I removed jq from the equation all together and instead used the while loop to construct a bash array, then transform that bash array into JSON compliant syntax in a way that satisfies my Rundeck use case:

```
#! /bin/bash

baseUrl=hostname/tenant:dir/
wget -q $baseUrl --output-document=output.xml

read_dom () {
    local IFS=\>
    read -d \< ELEMENT STRING
}

deploy=()
while read_dom; do
    if [[ $ELEMENT == "Key" ]] && [[ $STRING == *"STRING"* ]]; then
        deploy+=("${STRING}")
    fi
done < output.xml

if [ ! -f deploy.json ]; then touch deploy.json; fi
json="[$(printf '"%q",' "${deploy[@]}")"
json="${json%,}]"
echo "$json" > deploy.json
```

Output:

```
[user@hostname deploy]$ cat deploy.json
["someValue1","someValue2","someValue3","someValue4","someValue5","someValue6","someValue7","someValue8"]
```

I also removed the need for the condition around the no-match grep by simply continuing to filter what gets added to the array, and reconstruct the entire array instead of appending an additional object.

It probably wouldn't scale to be very performant over thousands of objects, but in my use case it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (hackish) solution would be to add one more invocation of jq along the lines of:

```
jq -s . deploy.json | sponge deploy.json
```

It might be worth your while, though, to think about how to eliminate the bash loop altogether, perhaps using an XML-to-JSON transmogrifier, or maybe better yet an XML wrapper for jq, such as https://github.com/kislyuk/yq.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to only ouptut the relevant value from inside the loop and have `jq` work on the output of the loop. It is made easier if you have the loop output correct JSON (strings must be enclosed in double quotes), as the combination of --raw-input and --slurp that is otherwise necessary requires splitting the input around \n.

```
while read_dom; do
    if [[ $ELEMENT == "Key" ]] && [[ $STRING == *"string"* ]]; then
        if ! grep -Fxq "{\"name\":\"${STRING}\",\"value\":\"${STRING}\"}" deploy.json; then
            echo "\"${STRING}\""
        fi
    fi
done < input.txt | jq --slurp 'map({ key: ., value: .})'
```

In that code the loop outputs something like that :

```
"someName1"
"someName2"
"someName3"
```

Then the `jq` command which receives that input works on an array of those JSON elements thanks to `--slurp`, which it transforms by mapping each element to an object with key/value fields as you can see [here](https://jqplay.org/s/dvTvhiKVKv).